# Sequelize db:migrate failing with sequelize deprecated string error

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am building an app in Nodejs using sequelize and mysql dialect. I can generate migrations just fine but cannot run them to populate tables in the database. this is what I am getting when I run db:migrate:

```
Sequelize CLI [Node: 8.9.4, CLI: 4.1.1, ORM: 4.38.1]

Loaded configuration file "config\config.json".
Using environment "development".
sequelize deprecated String based operators are now deprecated. Please use Symbo
l based operators for better security, read more at http://docs.sequelizejs.com/
manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators ..\..\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\no
de_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:242:13

ERROR: connect ETIMEDOUT
```

I have tried to set **operatorsAliases: false,** in database connection without luck.

**This is my database connection:**

```
'use strict';

var fs        = require('fs');
var path      = require('path');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var basename  = path.basename(__filename);
var env       = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
var db        = {};
const Op = Sequelize.Op;

if (config.use_env_variable) {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config,{ operatorsAliases: false });
} else {

  var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database,
   config.username,
    config.password,

     { 
  operatorsAliases: false,
  host: config.host,
  dialect: config.dialect,
    }
  );


  //check if connection is established
  sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Database Connection has been established successfully.');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    var model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});
db.sequelize = sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

The app is connecting to the database just fine. Initially I dint have this problem and migration performed then was successful. Adding retrieving records from existing tables with ORM is working just fine. But I cannot run new migrations to create new tables.

Any suggestion to fix the issue will appreciate. I can say I have tried the solutions available online but did not handle my case. Thank you.

Comment: Sequelize CLI warnings should not be the thing preventing your migration from executing, it's known issue AFAIK. Seems like Sequelize cannot connect to DB. Did you specify the database connection properly?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by replacing the Boolean attribute `false` by `0`.